# error when updating module

Tags: updating

I'm trying to update my `colorbox` module and I keep getting the error:

> Update failed! See the log below for more information. Your site is
>   still in maintenance mode.

and below it says:

**colorbox**

Error installing / updating
*File Transfer failed, reason: Cannot remove directory /home/content/02/12910502/html/sites/all/modules/colorbox/..*

**Next steps**
*Your modules have been downloaded and updated.
Run database updates*

why do I get this error and how can I get this fixed?

**EDIT1**
I'm using GoDaddy shared hosting. All permissions for files & directories in ftp are set to 755 (owner 12910502) within `colorbox/` but I still get this error... - I've never had a problem on other sites I'm working with, weird.
This is drupal core **7.15** - may that be the reason?

**EDIT2**
How abut if I just replace the directory onthe ftp with the latest version and then run `update.php`, should this work too?

Comment: WOW why on earth are you using 7.15 core? You need to update ASAP as there have been many security fixes. **EDIT2** sounds like a great idea.

Comment: **EDIT2** is what I ended up doing. As for why I'm with `7.15` - just because that was the latest when I built the site and I haven't touched it since unil now...

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like a permission issue.

If you're using ubuntu, make sure the user owner for your modules folder is www-data and 755 permission.

Also, don't forget to run `update.php` by going to `www.yourwebsite.com/update.php` after you update drupal core OR any module.

Comment: I changed my owner to the user-name (benwork) and the group name to www-data ... the permissions of www are (recursively) 755... I had no problems with this arrangement... In contrast to others (long story) :)

Comment: @benos oops my meant to say 755, thx.

Comment: please see **EDIT1** above

Answer (score 0):

I ended up upgrading the modules as I suggested in **EDIT2** above. Worked fine except `ctools`, that module is still pending...